# Fill a zero for missing days

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

For every day there is no data, I want to add a 0 into the array:
The code I did is wrong because it doesn't add a 0 for missing days.
Goes from 1, 2, 6.. should go 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 - and have zeros leading upto that 6. Results are below.

```
        var i = 1;
        var found = false;

        try {
            for (var x = 0; x < @ViewBag.MonthDays; x++) {
                i = 1;
                do{
                    found = false;
                    try {
                        if ( i == cheque[x].theDay) {
                            s2.push(cheque[x].theMoney * -1);
                            found = true;
                            console.log("Day: " + cheque[x].theDay + " i " + i);
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    catch (error) {
                        s2.push(0);
                    }
                    console.log(i == cheque[x].theDay, i, cheque[x].theDay);
                    i++

                } while ((i < @ViewBag.MonthDays))
                console.log(found == false);
                if (found == false)
                    s2.push(0);
            }
        }
        catch (error){
            s2.push(0);
        }
        console.log ("Push: " + s2);
```

Results:

```
Day: 1 i 1
false
false 1 2
Day: 2 i 2
false
false 1 6
false 2 6
false 3 6
false 4 6
false 5 6
Day: 6 i 6
```

Says Day: 6 i 6 when it matches.

I know there is a better way to do this, a method sort of like this:

```
items = items2.map( row => 
    //is there a matching row in items?
    items.filter( r => r.theString == row.theString).length ==  0 ? 
   //if not, fill with zeros
          {theString:0, theCount:0} : 
   //if there is, return the items' row
   items.filter( r => r.theString == row.theString)[0] );
```

but that just matches two arrays with each other. This one needs every day of the month covered.

Comment: What's the inner while loop for? You are also incrementing in the inner loop so that's why the index jumps from 2 to 6.

Comment: @Jasen The inner while loop was to go thru every day...

Comment: So you are counting cheques for each day of the month? Delay your output until after the loops. Push these into a new array and print that after the comparisons.

Comment: @Jasen eh fk a loop, I did it another way. See answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I've done it now:

```
            var monthD = new Array(@ViewBag.MonthDays)
                .join().split(',')
                .map(function(item, index){ return ++index;})
            console.log (monthD);

             cheque = monthD.map( row => 
                //is there a matching row in items?
                cheque.filter( r => r.theDay == row).length ==  0 ? 
               //if not, fill with zeros
                {theDay:0, theMoney:0} : 
               //if there is, return the items' row
               cheque.filter( r => r.theDay == row)[0] );

            try {
                for (var x = 0; x < @ViewBag.MonthDays; x++) {
                    s2.push(cheque[x].theMoney * -1);
                }
            }
            catch (error){
                s2.push(0);
            }
```

Much better and quicker method. Without all the confusing loops to mess with my mind.